# What does the business term 'blue sky laws' mean?

Tags: small-business, investing, business

I often hear 'blue sky laws' in reference to startup or early level businesses. What does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

Blue Sky Laws refer to various state laws requiring disclosure in new security offerings.

Here's a [summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_sky_law):

> A blue sky law is a state law in the United States that regulates the
>   offering and sale of securities to protect the public from fraud.
>   Though the specific provisions of these laws vary among states, they
>   all require the registration of all securities offerings and sales, as
>   well as of stockbrokers and brokerage firms. Each state's blue sky law
>   is administered by its appropriate regulatory agency, and most also
>   provide private causes of action for private investors who have been
>   injured by securities fraud.

[From the United States Securities and Exchange Commission](http://www.sec.gov/answers/bluesky.htm)

> Every state has its own securities laws—commonly known as "Blue Sky
>   Laws"—that are designed to protect investors against fraudulent sales
>   practices and activities. While these laws can vary from state to
>   state, most states laws typically require companies making small
>   offerings to register their offerings before they can be sold in a
>   particular state. The laws also license brokerage firms, their
>   brokers, and investment adviser representatives.

Comment: This is why I love the SE network; I can't believe I hadn't heard this term (or that my quick google search failed to pick it up...)